# How to add a non-synchronizable attribute to Hybris OOTB catalog aware model?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to add an attribute to, say ProductModel or any OOTB composed type, which is catalog aware.
With condition that this new attribute should not synchronize, eg. product reviews.
How can we achieve this by not editing any synchronization configuration manually in BO.

Any pointers will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you have 2 choice :**

-using this impex

```
INSERT_UPDATE SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig; syncJob(code)[unique = true]; attributeDescriptor(enclosingType(code), qualifier)[unique = true]; ; includedInSync[default= true]
```

-or customize `CatalogVersionSyncJob` and return null when

> acc.getDescriptor().getQualifier() = "your attribute's name"